# How to build as form with angular components

Tags: angular, dart

I want to build an authentication form with angular component and tried as follow:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #loginCtrl="ngForm">
    <div class="input">
         <material-input type="text"
                        class="login"
                        required
                        floatingLabel
                        label="User"
                        [(ngModel)]="login.user"
                        ngControl="user"
                        #user="ngForm"></material-input>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <material-input
                class="login"
                type="password"
                floatingLabel label="Password"
                [(ngModel)]="login.password">
        </material-input>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <material-input
                class="login"
                type="text"
                floatingLabel
                label="Language"
                [(ngModel)]="login.language">
        </material-input>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <material-button
                type="submit"
                raised
                class="btn-blue">
            Login
        </material-button>
    </div>
</form>
```

the function `onSubmit` does not get triggered at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you did should work. As workaround you can try

```
    <material-button
            (click)="loginCtrl.submit()"
            raised
            class="btn-blue">
        Login
    </material-button>
```

Comment: It would work, but that will breaks the concept of angular2 not?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly by "concept"

Comment: When you look the code above, the form tag `form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"` should execute, when I press the login button. But in my case, it does not execute at all.

Comment: That's why I said "I guess what you did should work". There might be better answers than mine but you can try it as a workaround. I'd have to investigate more to know for sure but don't have enough time.

Comment: If you have time, could you configure it out?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post but there are couple things I want to add to this to help others in the future that would have been helpful for me when i found this. I worked with a very similar scenario and here is what I found

First you are using the

```
<material-button type="submit">Login</material-button>
```

Based on what I found here:
https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/issues/132

material-button isn't actually backed by an html button. It is a div underneath. So it is infeasible to have it be a type="submit"

So if you want to use the material button then do this:

```
<material-button raised (trigger) = "onSubmit()">Login</material-button>
```

and exclude (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" from your form element like this:

```
<form #loginCtrl="ngForm">
```

Alternatively if you wanted to keep the form element the way it is then you would need to use an html button that would accept the type="submit" like this:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #loginCtrl="ngForm">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Hope this helps others!!